# передать данные из Realm в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, realm

Получаю данные из `json` и записываю их в БД `Realm`, как мне их потом передать в `RecyclerView` ?

***Feed.java***

```
public class Feed extends Fragment {

    private final String TAG = "log_tag";

    private Realm realm;
    private RealmResults<Article> art;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_recycler_view, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                ResponseColumn();
            }
        });

        Realm.init(getActivity());
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

        ResponseColumn();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(art)); //в этой строке показывает ошибку

        return view;
    }

    private void ResponseColumn() {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                return f.getDeclaredClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                return false;
            }
        }).create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        EngadgetAPI engadgetAPI = retrofit.create(EngadgetAPI.class);

        Call<EngadgetArticle> call = engadgetAPI.getArticle();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<EngadgetArticle>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EngadgetArticle> call, Response<EngadgetArticle> response) {

                realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                //realm.deleteAll();
                List<Article> article = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(response.body().getArticles());
                realm.commitTransaction();

                art = realm.where(Article.class).findAll();

                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: article = " + article.size());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: realm size = " + art.size());

                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.message());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<EngadgetArticle> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

***RecyclerViewAdapter.java***

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> implements RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Article>> {

    private final RealmResults<Article> articles;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(RealmResults<Article> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.articles.addChangeListener(this);//здесь тоже показывает ошибку
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Article> element) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        CardView cardView;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvDescription;
        TextView tvPublished;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            tvPublished = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPublished);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvTitle.setText(articles.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(articles.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.tvPublished.setText(articles.get(position).getPublishedAt());
        Picasso.with(holder.cardView.getContext())
                .load(articles.get(position).getUrlToImage())
                .error(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image)
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }
}
```

**UPD**  ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nikolai.engadgetnews, PID: 900
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int io.realm.RealmResults.size()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.nikolai.engadgetnews.RecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount(RecyclerViewAdapter.java:85)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3416)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3252)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3767)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:636)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1167)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:852)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:871)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                    at com.an
```

Comment: Кода много, ключевые слова вроде адаптер и холдер в нем присутствуют, значит мыль уже течет в нужном направлении. Расскажите подробнее, что не получается?

Comment: `art = realm.where(Article.class).findAll()` здесь получаю данные своей БД и `recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(art))` в конструкторе пробую передавать, но вылетает ошибка

Comment: что за ошибка? покажите лог

Comment: @tse добавил лог

Comment: в выборке из БД, которую вы передаете в адаптер, нет данных

Comment: @pavlofff я это вижу, но вопрос в том как правильно передать данные?

Comment: видимо проблема не в передаче, а в преобразовании из JSON. Почему бы вам все же не воспльзоваться для этого возможностями самой БД

Comment: Сейчас пробую разбираться с методами `createObjectFromJson()` и `createAllFromJson()`, но пока многое не понятно.

Comment: @pavlofff Пробую такой вариант
`final String json = String.valueOf(response.body().getArticles());`
`realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Article.class, json);`
но вываливается такая ошибка:
`Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value com.example.nikolai.engadgetnews.Feed.Article@6662dbf at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`
Не подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: Полученная строка не является форматом JSON (не может быть преобразована в JSONObject). Вы смотрели, что возвращает ваш метод в качестве JSON?

Comment: @pavlofff если я правильно понимаю, то проблема в том что response.body().getArticles() возвращает List<Article> и оно не может преобразовать его в JSONObject

Comment: вам нужео получать простую строку в формате JSON, без преобразования в список

Comment: Что делать, если [ответ помог](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

База данных Realm имеет свой [собственный адаптер](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#adapters) для `RecyclerView`/ На вход адаптер принимает непосредственно выборку из БД - колллекцию класса `OrderedRealmCollection` - абстрактный класс, реализации которого `RealmResults` или `RealmList`.

для импорта класса адаптера добавляем в файл build.gradle на уровене приложения следующее ([текущая версия](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters) адаптера 2.0.0):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
}
```

далее используем адаптер (без реализации переопределяемых методов адаптера для `RecyclerView`):

```
class MyRealmAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Data, MyRealmAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    public MyRealmAdapter (OrderedRealmCollection<Data> data) {
        super(data, true); //второй аргумент - флаг автообновления списка с обновлением данных.
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Data dataItem = getData().get(position);

   }

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
}
```

Где *getData()* - метод супер-класса, возвращающий выборку из БД, объект типа `RealmResults` или `RealmList`

PS: так же API Realm имеет методы для прямого преобразования JSON в записи БД `RealmObject` - `createObjectFromJson()` и `createAllFromJson()`. Сама Realm проделает эту операцию быстрее, чем ваш кустарный способ.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, для автообновления списка не нужно ли использовать никаких слушателей на обновление данных? Потому как вот этот источник говорит об обратном: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208379/realmrecyclerview-updates-only-after-switching-between-tabs-empty-view-appears