# Realm ошибка там, где нет Realm-a

Tags: android, realm, recyclerview.adapter

Удаляю элемент с коллекции в адаптере. В адаптере нет реалма, но приложение крашится с реалм ошибкой.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This method is not supported by 'RealmResults' or 'OrderedRealmCollectionSnapshot'.
at io.realm.OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.remove(OrderedRealmCollectionImpl.java:428)
at io.realm.RealmResults.remove(RealmResults.java:62)
at com.likhanov.mainwork.map.adapters.ProjectAdapter.removeRange(ProjectAdapter.java:71)
at com.likhanov.mainwork.map.adapters.ProjectAdapter.removeItems(ProjectAdapter.java:59)
at com.likhanov.mainwork.map.CalendarActivity$ActionModeCallback.onActionItemClicked(CalendarActivity.java:286)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onActionItemClicked(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1791)
at android.support.v7.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(StandaloneActionMode.java:140)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

В двух словах, когда это происходит.

Из класса активити, в котором есть Realm, я вызываю метод адаптера, находящийся в отдельном файле.

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
    mDataset.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

mDataset - это просто `List` в адаптере, собственно, при попытке удаления или добавления просто в этот список, происходит ошибка.

Comment: У Realm [есть адаптеры](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters), которые работают с их выборкой, зачем вы что то костылите? А в ошибке простыми английскими словами написано, что метод простой коллекции не имеет доступа к объектам из БД Realm (`RelmResults` напрямую связан с данными в БД), что не удивительно - удалять надо из самой БД и использовать соответствующий адаптер, который имеет колбэк на БД для обновления списка. Вот [пример](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/adapters/ui/recyclerview), как это все работает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/611421/177345

Comment: понял, спасибо. Заменю адаптеры на realm адаптеры.

Comment: Так же вы можете удалять прямо из выборки `RealmResults` - данная выборка напрямую связана с данными в БД и удаление\изменение в ней изменит и данные в самой базе.

Comment: @pavlofff надо ли после этого вызывать notify методы у адаптера?

Comment: если вторым аргументом в супер-конструкторе адаптера стоит `true` (ключ autoupdate), то список будет автоматически обновляться при обновлении данных в БД, любые методы обновления вызывать не надо. Смотрите [документацию](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/adapter/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.html) (вторая строчка в описании класса)